# Memory Error (500) For SMTP Settings After Upgrading to 5.35.1

Tags: civimail, smtp

After upgrading to 5.35.1 I am getting a memory limit reached error when loading the SMTP settings page. I am not sure if this is related but I am getting a growl error for "Failed to find key by ID or tag" and then a random string.

I have tried getting to the page with and without the CiviCRM Secret Keys set in my settings file. I have cleared the cache. My memory limit is set at an obscene 3000M.

I have this working on my dev server with the same SMTP settings.  The dev server has the CiviCRM Secret Keys set.  I am using;

```
define('CIVICRM_CRED_KEYS', '::SOME VALUE');
```

Any help or ideas of how to fix this are appreciated.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Can you confirm the version, 5.31.1 is pretty old and has security vulnerabilities that are fixed in 5.35.1 :-)

Comment: Thank you it is 5.35.1. Yikes, sorry!

Answer (score 1):

What I think happened is that added the encryption key after I did the upgrade. I am not sure how I did this.  This was then causing the SMTP key not to be able to be read.

I got the idea that maybe I could force blank values into the STMP form. While there I found this code.

```
if (!empty($this->_defaults['smtpPassword'])) {
          $this->_defaults['smtpPassword'] = \Civi::service('crypto.token')->decrypt($this->_defaults['smtpPassword']$
        }
```

I commented this out and the form loaded.  I saved without the key in the civicrm.settings.php file and then with the key again.

Now everything works correctly again.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you. I was getting an error "failed to find key by id or tag civicrm"

Answer (score 1):

In case others need to resolve this issue with the input of this SQL command `DELETE from civicrm_setting WHERE name = 'mailing_backend';`
I could access to the SMTP settings page right after.